# "Prevent keep seeing it" or "prevent keeping seeing it"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Example sentence:

> To prevent **keep/keeping** seeing Mary naked, Tom dressed her in one
>   of his T-shirt and his cleanest shorts.

Should it be keep or keeping? And why?

I searched for "prevent keep seeing" or "prevent keeping seeing" on Google but didn't find any results.

Comment: I would go like: *To prevent himself from keeping seeing Mary naked, Tom dressed her in one of his T-shirt and his cleanest shorts*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very awkward construction. Try replacing it with "To keep from seeing," or "To avoid seeing ... again," or "dressed her in one of his T-shirts and his cleanest shorts so she wouldn't be naked." I think the idea that if someone is naked they would be seen naked repeatedly or continuously is obvious and doesn't need to be stated.