# Two ing-verbs in a row: "while keeping doing something". Is it awkward to you?

Tags: verbs

I was about to write following sentence: "to send information back while keeping regulating the position of the actuator", but I always feel awkward about using two ing-verbs in a row. So I ask you.

Perhaps is there an elegant alternative that means exactly the same, but I would also be interested in knowing how "keeping doing" sounds for native anglophones.

My question is somewhat similar to the following, but there wasn't a satisfactory answer in my view.
["Prevent keep seeing it" or "prevent keeping seeing it"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147639/prevent-keep-seeing-it-or-prevent-keeping-seeing-it)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is *very informal* (so you should prefer the expressions in the accepted answer to this), but there *is* a simple way of splitting up the two verbs without changing anything else: "to send information back while keeping **on** regulating the position of the actuator."  "Keep on [doing something]" has a very similar meaning to "keep [doing something]."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does sound awkward. An equivalent would be "while continuing to regulate the position of the actuator". If you don't need the emphasis provided by "continuing to regulate", you could just drop it: "while regulating the position of the actuator".

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! I feel continue is quite formal, which is good in the current case, but I will take note of just dropping the verb 'to keep' in informal speech :) And if I really need to convey the nuance of continuity, I can just use 'still': "while still regulating the position..."